# Capybara+Selemium: How to initialize database in an integration test code and make it visible in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, transactions, selenium, capybara

**Configuration:**
Integration tests for Rails project using RSpec, Capybara, Selemium driver, SQLite database.

**Situation:**
I had few integration tests with Capybara and default rack_test driver. They create a user registration (for Devise gem) directly in database. Then they login and test a scenario using Capybara DSL like a user would do.

**Problem:**
I tried to change a driver to Selenium to test JavaScript code as well. Now the tests fail because application does not see a user registration that the tests created.

**Investigation:**
It looks like Selenium driver works differently with transations, so changes made in a test are invisible in the web application. Possible solution make involve:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false 
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me worked solution from [here](https://github.com/lailsonbm/contact_manager_app) and [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/13057):

- add to Gemfile `gem database_cleaner`
- create file `spec/support/javascript.rb` with content

`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    if example.metadata[:js]
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.use_default_driver if example.metadata[:js]
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

`

though it caused small penalti to my contoller & model specs execution time (from 40 to 43 seconds).

Comment: did not work for me "'example' is not available from within an example (e.g. an 'it' block or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. before, let, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a describe or context block)". Capybara 2.6.2, Rspec 3.4.0, Rails 4.2.1